# Font size in Jitsi

Tags: fonts, voip

I have installed Jitsi and as I have read that is highly customizable I want to change the font size as it is really small. But I don't want to configure it via the properties of Ubuntu and enlarge the fonts everywhere. I just want to change the font size in Jitsi. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not happy with this solution, but I have found that editing the `/usr/bin/jitsi` script and changing the JVM CLIENTARGS to …

`-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2.0`

… helped.

I only changed lines 7 and 11 here:

```bsh
/usr/bin/jitsi

#!/bin/bash

# Get architecture
ARCH=`uname -m | sed -e s/x86_64/64/ -e s/i.86/32/`

# Additionnal JVM arguments
CLIENTARGS="-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2.0"

if [ $ARCH -eq 32 ]
then
    CLIENTARGS="$CLIENTARGS -client -Xmx256m"
fi

---snip---
```

Would love a better solution.